# Shell script: Copy a folder but create only empty files with correct name and time stamp?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, timestamp

I want to create a clone of a folder. But the clone should only have empty files in it. But with correct name and time stamp.

The code I use ATM works fine, but looses the correct time stamp:

```
ls /media/SSD/Folder > /tmp/structure.txt

while read LINE
do  touch /media/SSD/Folder_Clone/"$LINE.txt"
done < /tmp/structure.txt

exit
```

What do I need to change, to keep the correct time stamp?

Comment: [Do not parse the output of `ls`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Thomas123: If the target file already exists and is non-empty, it will still be non-empty afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reference option of [`touch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html).

```
cd /media/SSD/Folder
for f in *; do
  touch -r "$f" /media/SSD/Folder_Clone/"$f"
done
```

Comment: To guarantee that the file is empty, I would do a `>` before the `touch -r`.